# fadeTo not working in ie10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am not sure why but after looking at examples I thought were the same from previous questions I decided to post.. I have a button when clicked does the following things...

```
$('.fa-phone, .bg-darkPink').parent().on('click', function () {
      $('#testimonials').fadeTo(0, 0); 
      $('.submenu-ctn').fadeTo(0, 0); 
      $("#colorscreen").remove();
      $("body").append('<div id="colorscreen" class="animated"></div>');
      $("#colorscreen").addClass("fadeInUpBigCS");
      $(".musability-music-therapy-content-space").css({width: "720px",opacity:1}).load("contact-page.html #contact-form");
      $(".submenu-ctn").load("contact-page.html .submenu-contact");
      $.getScript("js/slider/slider-animations.js");
      $(".submenu-ctn").load("contact-page.html .submenu-contact");
      $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');  
      $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('collapse');
      $('.submenu-ctn').fadeTo(3000, 1);
});
```

the problem is that this bit of the script is not getting executed.

```
$('#testimonials').fadeTo(0, 0);
```

where the css and html is as follows

```
<div id="testimonials">  

<div class="box animated seven boxGreen testimonials1">
    <p class="fg-white">"".<p class="text-small fg-white">- M
        <span class="imagestars">
        <img src="images/mthc/stars.png" alt="testimoinal rating 5 star">
        </span>
    </p>
</div>

<div class="box animated nine boxGreen testimonials2">
    <p class="fg-white">" the long term"<p class="text-small fg-white">kool.
        <span class="imagestars">
        <img src="images/mthc/stars.png" alt="testimoinal rating 5 star">
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
</div>

#testimonials
{
    display:block;
    opacity:1;
    z-index:1500;
}
```

Not really sure what's going on so investigating with debug but that isn't telling anything atm.  works in all other browsers hmmmm ?

Comment: I see 2 possibilities: 1/ You have an syntax error caught by IE but not other browsers (IE is more strict on these); 2/ jQuery use css property "opacity" and you're on an old IE which does not know it. First step would be checking IE and jQuery version.. EDIT: It may be from your CSS, since opacity will not work in older IE versions.

Comment: internet explorer 10 and jquery 2.1.4

Comment: it is strange that the other lines in the script do work even in i.e 9 ?

Comment: Try this link in IE 10 http://malsup.com/jquery/fadetest.html

Comment: and yet it fades the class submenu-ctn , maybe i should change my div to a class ?

Comment: that didn't seem to work , ok since there are only a couple of properties in the css maybe i need to get rid of display:block ?

Comment: OK so it's not about opacity (working since IE9). By the way I made a fiddle (working in IE): https://jsfiddle.net/smv3mskw/ There are errors in your html markup, IE could choke on that, too.

Comment: no errors on the page itself either , this is very strange and if the page had erros why does submenu-ctn fade

Comment: Try switching the fadeTo for submenu-ctn and testimonials around and see what happens

Comment: yup agreed, trying that now , and i am also trying to fadeto the classes within the div as well

Comment: that didn't seem to work , I am copying the css of submenu-ctn to see what happens

Comment: i suspect this is a css issue but not sure what , one sec

Comment: GOT IT WORKING ! basically the overflow:hidden needed to be removed from the sub classes within the div .... that sorted the problem out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically I.E 10 doesn't like classes that have overflow:hidden within a div you are trying to fadeTo ... taking them out of the classes within the div sorted the problem out !